# Apparent disparity between the results of two papers (nearest neighbours)

Tags: pr.probability

This is a follow up question [this one on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459484/expected-number-of-people-to-not-get-shot), which can basically be summarised as Robert Abilock originally posed in *American Monthly* in 1967:

[The Rifle-Problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2314274?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

> $n$ riflemen are distributed at random points on a plane. At a signal,
>   each one shoots at and kills his nearest neighbor. What is the expected
>   number of riflemen who are left alive?

In my answer, I cited two apparently conflicting references

  [Vicious neighbor problem](http://nuweb9.neu.edu/fwu/wp-content/uploads/Wu111_JPA20_L299.pdf)
  [R.Tao and F.Y.Wu; 1986], where the answer of $\approx 0.284051 n$ remaining riflemen was given as the solution in $2$ dimensions.

and

  [Mathematical Constants: Nearest-neighbor graphs](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/nng.pdf)
  [S.R.Finch; 2008], where Finch states that

> In [*Vicious neighbor problem*], the absolute value signs in the definitions of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ were mistakenly omitted.)$\dots$

I have tried to replicate even the partial results in Tao/Wu's paper *(despite leaving out the absolute values of $\varphi$ and $\psi,$)* leaving me unsure as to whether I am missing something in my *"translation"* of the problem into Finch's more modern notation. I should be most grateful if someone could illuminate me further in this matter.

Comment: You write random points on a plane in the first source, and the second source mention a unit cube. 
Can the discrepancy depend on the shape of the bounded region where the shooters are?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson the Tao/Wu paper disregards boundary conditions, but as far as I am aware, in $3$ dimensions, they give $\operatorname{E}[n]/n \approx 0.303,$ which Finch doesn't dispute.

Comment: So I did a python simulation, in which there were 20 shooters uniformly distributed in the unit square together with 1 at the centre. In 1000000 trials, the guy at the centre survived 28.1% of the time. This should be within about $\pm 0.1$% of the correct value if there are 20+1 shooters. (by working with a shooter at the centre, we're avoiding edge effects). I might try increasing 20 to see if anything changes...

Comment: With 40+1 shooters, the central guy survived with probability 28.4%$\pm 0.1$%.

Comment: good question, an interesting side-glance, how many rounds are fired before a stalemate?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Sorry, you have lost me - do you mean cases where all participants are shot?

Comment: @martin; one might survive (and if so which one?) - just asking after round one is the distribution still 'random'?. also patterns might occur on say a integer lattice (game of death!)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Each round (or trial) should be independent, I don't see how  distribution could be anything other than random.

Comment: because all the 'clingy' types have been eliminated?

Comment: also if i gave you a grid, where would YOU stand? bounded obviously

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I'm afraid I don't follow - if you think this is relevant, or that you have noticed an important point that has been overlooked, please feel free to post an answer, neither here, or to the original MSE question in the link above.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry as $n$ grows large, boundary effects become negligable (see D.Thomine's comment below my answer on MSE).